# Spacemacs keeps installing and uninstalling auctex-latexmk

Tags: spacemacs, latex, auctex

Running spacemacs 0.200.13.

Everytime I start spacemacs, it either installs auctex-latexmk or deletes it saying that it is an orphan package.

Here is some more information:

- I have latex layer enabled
- I also have a private layer. But that does not have anything to do with latex or auctex

What is going wrong here? How do I set things right?

Comment: same issue here. any hints on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try the fix given at https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/8467#issuecomment-284254636

It fixed the issue for me, replacing just `latex` in the layers list with

```
(latex :variables latex-build-command "LatexMk")
```

`auctex-latexmk` gets installed and remains installed after this change.